# Macbook Air camera is not working since I switched from macOS to Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, mac, webcam

Ever since I moved to Ubuntu from macOS, Ubuntu can't find the camera in my computer

I am using a 2015 macbook air and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

`lsusb` outputs this:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 125f:a88a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:0291 Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05ac:828f Apple, Inc. BRCM20702 Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2109:8817 VIA Labs, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c092 Logitech, Inc. BRCM20702 Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```